# error al intentar generar un query desde angular 9

Tags: php, javascript, angular

[image: Tengo el código que muestro en la imagen,], si ese código lo ejecuto con POSTMAN (como se muestra en la imagen funciona perfectamente y me devuelve un string  (que muestro en la imagen) "registro insertado",
sin embargo si desde el navegador envío la misma url (http://localhost:4000/updDb/(%22insert%20into%20programacxp%20 (fechapago,%20semana,%20concepto,%20proyecto,%20importe,%20proved,%20status, %20clasif,%20periodo,%20dias,%20aplicado)%20values%20
('2020-07-17',%20'0',%20'RECOLECCI%C3%93N%20DE%20BASURA%20',
%20'7E313-2732', %20'100.00',%20'DDF',%20'true',
'GASTO%20DE%20ADMON',%20'0',%20'5',%20'false')%22),
me  devuelve el siguiente error:

The requested resource /updDb/(%22insert%20into%20programacxp%20(fechapago,%20semana,%20concepto,%20proyecto,%20importe,%20proved,%20status,%20clasif,%20periodo,%20dias,%20aplicado)%20values%20('2020-07-17',%20'0',%20'RECOLECCI%C3%93N%20DE%20BASURA%20',%20'7E313-C2732',%20'100.00',%20'DDF',%20'true','GASTO%20DE%20ADMON',%20'0',%20'5',%20'false')%22) was not found on this serve.

No obstante que el query es exactamente igual.
este es el código que envía el query al backend en Angular 9:

```
modDb(jsonquery){
        let query = '\"'+jsonquery+'\"';
        let consulta = this.url+'updDb/('+query+')'; //aquí invoco al servidor...
        console.log (consulta); // verifico que la consulta esté bien construida....
        let respuesta = this._http.get(consulta).pipe(map(res =>res));
        console.log(respuesta);
        return respuesta;   
}
```

el console.log me devuelve:

```
insert into programacxp 
      (fechapago, semana, concepto, proyecto, 
       importe, proved, status, clasif, periodo, dias, aplicado) 
   values 
     ('2020-07-17', '0', 'RECOLECCIÓN DE BASURA ', '7E313-C2732', 
       '100.00', 'DDF', 'true','GASTO DE ADMON', '0', '5', 'false')
```

Me podrían ayudar a encontrar el error?? gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `this.url` en Angular? Puede que por ahí esté el fallo.

Comment: Por cierto, la imagen de Postman apenas se distingue nada. Es demasiado pequeña.

Comment: Ahora que me fijo en lo que haces con la URL, estás enviando código SQL directamente en la URL. Eso es una malísima práctica. No es que expongas el servidor a SQL Injection, es que directamente se lo pones en bandeja de plata. Cuidado con eso.

Comment: Hola sergio, la url de this.url es la misma :http://localhost:4000/

Comment: y claro tienes razón, mi intención era crear un array mas o menos asi: [tabla: programacxp, opcion: 1 data: {campo1: valor.........campoN: valor}], pero no supe como pasarle este objeto desde angulas a mi midleware ( te comento que mi server aplication, es un Datasnap Server y ya tengo en el la función que recibe un tJsonArray, y de acuerdo a la opción recibida (1= insert, 2= update, 3 = delete) genera internamente la consulta)

Comment: Si importas `@angular/forms` puedes hacer uso de `FormData`, que te serviría para este propósito de generar un objeto JSON. Eso sí, en vez de ir en la propia URL, lo mete como body de la petición.

Comment: Te comento brevemente: tengo un servidor